# How to delete everything between angle brackets in VIM globally?

Tags: vim

Say I have a text such as

```
file.wav;0.000;12.015;Spreker-C;;;<lang:English> Yes </lang:English> Niko. <lang:English> Yes </lang:English> Niko, gaan ons verder praat oor die #um leerbesigheid? [no-speech]
```

and I want to delete everything between the angle brackets so i would have

```
file.wav;0.000;12.015;Spreker-C;;;Yes Niko. Yes Niko, gaan ons verder praat oor die #um leerbesigheid? [no-speech]
```

How do I do it globally?

If it was just one line, it would be an easy solution such as `da<`. However how do I delete everything for all lines in the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search and replace with `:s/<.\{-}>//g` should work, assuming you don't have nested `<>`. `<.\{-}>` is a pattern that matches brackets and content inside in a non-greedy manner;